# Magento 2: Page tittle is Printing below the content

Tags: magento2, dashboard, title

there is a problem my all page title are displaying below the content.
here is a screenshot.
[image]

please suggest a solution.

Comment: show you customer_account.xml code.

Comment: Hi, were you ever able to solve this?  I just noticed that **"My Dashboard"** page title is displaying at the bottom. Only in `customer/account/` page. I even reverted my theme from another staging instance (title displays correctly there), but still.

Answer (score 4):

1) Override the **customer_account.xml** file to your theme.

2)Then add the below content into it .

```
<page layout="2columns-left" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

   <body>
       <move element="page.main.title" destination="content" before="-"/>
   </body>
</page>
```

3)Clear the cache.

4)If your site mode is production then deploy static contents.

Comment: hi thanks but it didnt work in my case, i have `customer_account.xml` in my layout folder but still the title is displaying below the content

Comment: This should work !, I think you have modified some other layout in your respected theme. Please mention your magento version.    OR CHANGE destination = "content"    to destination="content.top"

Comment: version is 2.1.7 and i dont think i have modified any layout or what

Comment: If this also have a concern then add "move tag" (<move element="page.main.title" destination="content" before="-"/>) before the body close.

Comment: i did but got no results.

Comment: title is still below

Answer (score 0):

Refer this

https://mage2.pro/t/topic/1990

> vendor/magento/module_theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

change (Line no. 105)

```
<container name="content.top" label="Main Content Top"/>
```

to

```
<container name="content.top" label="Main Content Top" before="-"/>
```

Comment: You should really avoid modifying core files, the alternative answer above does avoid that and works perfectly: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/190855/3830